# git log --graph does not show branches, it only shows them as commits on master

Tags: git, github, gitlab

A time ago, at the institution I work for, the log graph of git used to show the commits in each branch before merging them into master, but now when we merge a branch it only shows them as commits on master, and does not show the history of the branches
This did not happen before. Why is it happening this way?
Thank you

```
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|    
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|    
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|  
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit
| 
| 
| 
| 
| 
* commit
| 
| 
| 
|    
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|  
* commit
| 
| 
| 
|    
|  
* commit
| 
| 
| 
|     
|    
*   commit 
|\  
| | 
| | 
| | 
| |     
| |   
| * commit 
| | 
| | 
| | 
| |     
| |   
* | commit 
|/  
|   
|   
|       
|  
* commit 
| 
| 
| 
|     
|    
*   commit
|\  
| | 
| | 
| | 
| |    
| |     
| *   commit
| |\  
| | | 
| | | 
| | | 
| | |     
| | |    
| | * commit
| | | 
| | | 
| | | 
| | |     
| | |    
| | * commit
| | | 
| | |
```

[image: git_log_graph]

Comment: Are you looking for `git log --graph --decorate` ? `git log --graph --all` ? or `git log --graph my/branch` ?

Comment: `git log --all --decorate --graph`

Comment: Note that there's also a `log.decorate` configuration knob in Git (since one-point-something I think, but not documented until 2-point-something. The release notes mention that the `auto` value (now the default) was new in 2.1, and there was a bug in the setting (where setting it to `false` failed) fixed in 2.13.1. So, check your Git version, and your `log.decorate` setting if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Git attempts to perform a "fast-forward" merge, where it will basically take the commits from one branch and replay them atop the merge target. This only works if the merge target has had no commits made to it in the meantime (iirc), but it means that the branch being merged in is effectively removed from the process, Git can just fast-forward master up to meet its tip without actually doing any merging.

You can disable this feature with 'git merge --no-ff'

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think you are looking for one of `git log`'s options :

- to add the name of branches and tags in your log, use `--decorate` :
  `git log --graph --decorate`
- to have a view of all branches in your repo, use `--all` :
  `git log --graph --all`

Note that you can combine both :

```
git log --graph --all --decorate
```